# The action 'report' could not be found for MedicalRecordsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ocurre lo siguiente,

### Tengo esto en las rutas:

```
resources :professionals do
    #...
    resources :medical_records, controller: 'medical_records', only: [] do
      collection do
        get :report
      end
    end
  end
```

### Y la `action` dentro de `MedicalRecordsController` existe y es esta:

```
def report
    medical_records_scope = begin_of_association_chain.order('active DESC')
    medical_records_scope = medical_records_scope.like(params[:filter].strip) if params[:filter]

    @medical_records_report = medical_records_scope

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="medical_records.xlsx"'
        render disposition: 'inline'
      }
    end
  end
```

El mensaje de error es el del título, que no encuentra la acción.
Según la documentación

```
The action 'report' could not be found for MedicalRecordsController
```

Comment: ¿Que te retorna `rake routes`? Agrégalo en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **¡Solucionado!**

Tenía `def report` debajo de un `private`

Así

```
private
def report
    medical_records_scope = begin_of_association_chain.order('active DESC')
    medical_records_scope = medical_records_scope.like(params[:filter].strip) if params[:filter]

    @medical_records_report = medical_records_scope

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="medical_records.xlsx"'
        render disposition: 'inline'
      }
    end
  end
```

subido arriba y listo.